# I'm getting this error while trying to deploy a nextjs app on vercel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, next.js, vercel

Why you should I do [this](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updatingregularly) regularly as instructed in the provided link.

```
Info  - Creating an optimized production build...
Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
```

You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following [URL](https://nextjs.org/telemetry):

```
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db

Failed to compile.

./assets/openMDB.png 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)


> Build error occurred
Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:15:918
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:5:584)
error Command failed with exit code 1.

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1
```

Please can anyone help me and fix this issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced an almost similar problem. Those steps were worked for me.

- Delete node_modules
- run `npm install` command
- run `npm run build` command (here you can find out your build error info. if occurs error try to fixed then deploy again)
- If you have an SSR issue with a specific package, then you can use [dynamic import](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import) with `ssr:false` => `const dynamicImport = dynamic(() => import("package-name"), { ssr: false });`